# rvest package - Is it possible for html_text() to store an NA value if it does not find an attribute?

Tags: r, rvest

As the title states, I'm curious if it is possible for the `html_text()` function from the `rvest` package to store an `NA` value if it is not able to find an attribute on a specific page.

I'm currently running a scrape over 199 pages (which works fine; tested on a few variables already).

Currently, when I search for a value that is only present on a some (136) of the 199 pages, `html_text()` is only returning a vector of 136 strings. This is not useful because without `NA`s I am unable to determine which pages contained the variable in question.

I see that `html_atts()` is able to receive a `default` input, but not `html_text()`. Any tips?

Thank you so much!

Comment: is there any way to provide a small sample of a few URLs with the data and a few without?

Answer (score 7):

If you create a new function to wrap error handling, it'll keep the `%>%` pipe cleaner and easier to grok for your future self and others:

```
library(rvest)

html_text_na <- function(x, ...) {

  txt <- try(html_text(x, ...))
  if (inherits(txt, "try-error") |
      (length(txt)==0)) { return(NA) }
  return(txt)

}

base_url <- "http://www.saem.org/membership/services/residency-directory?RecordID=%d"

record_id <- c(1291, 1000, 1166, 1232, 999)

sapply(record_id, function(i) {

  html(sprintf(base_url, i)) %>% 
    html_nodes("#drpict tr:nth-child(6) .text") %>%
    html_text_na %>%
    as.numeric()

})

## [1]  8 NA 10 27 NA
```

Also, by doing an `sapply` over the vector of `record_id`'s you automagically get a vector back of whatever value that is you're trying to extract.

Comment: Neat! Thank you for the tips! I'm a bit embarrassed for using a for loop, but that's just what I was most comfortable with... Definitely going to use your method the next go-around!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out.

I just needed to add a line of logic to my loop.

Here's a chunk of the code that worked:

```
for(i in record_id) {
  site <- paste("http://www.saem.org/membership/services/residency-directory?RecordID=", i, sep="")
  site <- html(site)
  this_data <- site %>%
                html_nodes("#drpict tr:nth-child(6) .text") %>%
                html_text() %>%
                as.numeric()
  if(length(this_data) == 0) {
    this_data <- NA
  }
  all_data <- c(all_data, this_data)
}
```

Thanks anyway everybody (and @hrbrmstr)! :)

Comment: Well-done! I'd suggest making a wrapper function for `html_text` that does the length check and returns `NA` vs `NULL` for production code.

Comment: Totally a novice here, would you mind explaining that further? Greatly appreciate the help and suggestions!